# Reschedule DAG on task success/failure

Tags: python, airflow-scheduler, airflow

Consider a very simple Apache Airflow DAG:

```
FileSensor -> PythonOperator
```

where `FileSensor` is waiting for some files to appear (with relatively short `poke_interval`) and `PythonOperator` processes these files. This DAG is scheduled `@once` to run indefinitely - how could I set it to be rescheduled to run again from within the `PythonOperator` after it succeeds (or fails)?

Comment: Never tried this but maybe setting a 3rd task of TriggerDagRunOperator that triggers the same dag might work. try : `TriggerDagRunOperator(task_id='trigger', dag_id='your_dag_id')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as [@Elad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14624409/elad) suggested, [`TriggerDagRunOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun/index.html#airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun.TriggerDagRunOperator) was the way to go. In conjunction with `reset_dag_run` and `execution_date` parameters, I was able to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

In general I think Elad's suggestion might work, however I would argue it's a bad practice. DAGs are by design (and name) acyclic, so creating any types of loops within it might cause it to behave unexpectedly.

Also based on Airflow documentation you should set your dag schedule to None if you plan to use external dag trigger. Personally I'm not sure if it will necessarily break something, but it definitely can give you outputs you don't expect. Probably will take you longer to debug it later as well, if something goes wrong.

IMHO better approach would be for you try and to rethink your design. In case you need to reschedule dag on failure you can take advantage of reschedule mode for sensor https://www.astronomer.io/guides/what-is-a-sensor . Not sure why you would want to re-run it on success, if it's the case of multiple files in the source, I would say rather create multiple sensors with variable parameter and  for loop in your dag script.

Comment: The basic idea was to continuously process files upon arrival in folder. So after `trigger_dag -> sense_file(s) -> process -> dag_completed` I would simply like to re-run it to be able to sense future incoming files.